# mongodb duplicate remove in large size fields(119 fields)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 9 million document and each document 119 fields

```
{  "_id" : 0,"field_1" : "value" , .....,"field_118" : "value" }
...
...
...
{  "_id" : 8999999,"field_1" : "value" , .....,"field_118" : "value" }
```

I tried

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"field_1":1,"field_2":1,....,"field_118":1}, {unique : true, dropDups : true})
```

i got a error message

```
"errmsg" : "namespace name generated from index name \"....(fields)..\" is too long (127 byte max)", "code" : 67
```

how to solve ?

Comment: The dropDups option has been deprecated since MongoDB 2.6... Which mongodb are you using?

Comment: mongoDB version 2.6.10

Comment: The dropDups option will not work. You will need to manually remove the duplicate fields or use a script.

Comment: I find it hard to belive that *119 fields* form a unqiue set of values in combination. At most you only likely have a few fields that actually make a document "unique" and can otherwise deal with discarding or otherwise dealing with the other varying values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove dups from mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557053/remove-dups-from-mongodb)

Comment: i want to scrip file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557053/remove-dups-from-mongodb dose not work

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the auto-generated name of your index has exceeded the index name length.

From [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Name-Length):

> Index Name Length Fully qualified index names, which includes the
> namespace and the dot separators (i.e. ..$), cannot be longer than 128 characters.
>
> By default,  is the concatenation of the field names and
> index type. You can explicitly specify the  to the
> createIndex() method to ensure that the fully qualified index name
> does not exceed the limit.

So, specify your own index name for your index in *ensureIndex* or *createIndex* options parameter:

```
{unique : true, name: myAwesomeIndex}
```

Comment: As already stated, the "dropDups" option was deprecated at the 2.6.0 release and has since been removed.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks, removed from my example.