# Removing duplicates from a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb where every document has a duplicate. There are 76 keys in each document and each one has one duplicate. I tried using the following technique to remove the duplicates

```
db.day1.aggregate([
{ "$group": {
    "_id": { "text": "$text" },
    "dups": { "$push": "$_id" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
{ "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
doc.dups.shift();
db.day1.remove({ "$in": doc.dups });
})
```

"text" is one of the duplicate keys. Even after doing this the duplicates didn't get removed. The problem is that the only unique field for a document is the "_id". Rest all are duplicated. Can someone help on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove dups from mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557053/remove-dups-from-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks @user3100115. I checked the answer. My problem is the only unique field is "_id". All the others are duplicated.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32659948/edit) your question to add why the possible duplicate didn't work for you.