# How to remove duplicates with a certain condition in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example, I have the following documents in my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "GuqXmAkkARqhBDqhy",
    "beatmapset_id" : "342537",
    "version" : "MX",
    "diff_approach" : "5",
    "artist" : "Yousei Teikoku",
    "title" : "Kokou no Sousei",
    "difficultyrating" : "3.5552737712860107"
}
{
    "_id" : "oHLT7KqsB7bztBGvu",
    "beatmapset_id" : "342537",
    "version" : "HD",
    "diff_approach" : "5",
    "artist" : "Yousei Teikoku",
    "title" : "Kokou no Sousei",
    "difficultyrating" : "2.7515676021575928"
}
{
    "_id" : "GbotZfrPEwW69FkGD",
    "beatmapset_id" : "342537",
    "version" : "NM",
    "diff_approach" : "5",
    "artist" : "Yousei Teikoku",
    "title" : "Kokou no Sousei",
    "difficultyrating" : "0"
}
```

These documents have the same key `beatmapset_id`
I want to delete all duplicates but leave the document with the most `difficultyrating`.

I tried `db.collection.ensureIndex({beatmapset_id: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})` but it leaves a random document and I want the condition above.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to update your documents and change `difficultyrating` and `beatmapset_id` to float point number. To do that you need to loop over each document using the [**`.forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and update each document with ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find/) operations for maximum efficiency..

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    bulk.find({ '_id': doc._id }).update({ 
        '$set': { 
            'beatmapset_id': parseFloat(doc.beatmapset_id), 
            'difficultyrating': parseFloat(doc.difficultyrating) 
        } 
    });
    count++; 
    if(count % 100 == 0) {     
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

if(count > 0) { 
    bulk.execute(); 
}
```

Now and since The "dropDups" syntax for index creation has been "deprecated" as of MongoDB 2.6 and removed in MongoDB 3.0. This is how you can remove the dups.

The main idea here is first sort your document by `difficultyrating` in descending order.

```js
bulk  = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
count = 0;
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$sort': { 'difficultyrating': -1 }}, 
    { '$group': { '_id': '$beatmapset_id', 'ids': { '$push': '$_id' }, 'count': { '$sum': 1 }}}, 
    { '$match': { 'count': { '$gt': 1 }}}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ids.shift();
    bulk.find({'_id': { '$in': doc.ids }}).remove(); 
    count++; 
    if(count === 100) { 
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if(count !== 0) { 
    bulk.execute(); 
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557053/remove-dups-from-mongodb) cover the topic for more detail.

Comment: Okay, turns out meteor can do bulk operations with collection.rawCollection() method.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take is to get a list of the unique ids of the documents with the duplicate **`beatmapset_id`** via the aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$beatmapset_id",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "uniqueIds": { "$addToSet": "$_id" },
            "maxRating": { "$max": "$difficultyrating" }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "count": { "$gte": 2 } 
        } 
    },
    { 
        "$sort" : { "count" : -1 } 
    }
]);
```

In the first stage of this example pipeline, we use the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)** operator to aggregate documents by the desired index key values and record (in the uniqueIds field) each `_id` value of the grouped documents. We also count the number of grouped documents by using the **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operator which adds up the values of the fields passed to it, in this case the constant 1 - thereby counting the number of grouped records into the count field. We also get the maximum `difficultyrating` value of the group by using the **[`$max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)** operator.

In the second stage of this example pipeline, we use the **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator to filter out all documents with a count of 1. The filtered-out documents represent unique index keys.

The remaining documents identify documents in the collection that contain duplicate keys.

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "342537",
            "count" : 3,
            "uniqueIds" : [ 
                "GbotZfrPEwW69FkGD", 
                "oHLT7KqsB7bztBGvu", 
                "GuqXmAkkARqhBDqhy"
            ],
            "maxRating" : "3.5552737712860107"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Since the **[`db.collection.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method returns a cursor and can return result sets of any size, use the **[cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor)** method **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** to iterate the cursor and access the result documents that you can then streamline with **[Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk)** **[`remove`](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/84922794768/mongodbs-new-bulk-api)** operations:

```
var pipeline = [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$beatmapset_id",
                "count": { "$sum": 1 },
                "uniqueIds": { "$addToSet": "$_id" },
                "maxRating": { "$max": "$difficultyrating" }
            }
        },
        { 
            "$match": { 
                "count": { "$gte": 2 } 
            } 
        },
        { 
            "$sort" : { "count" : -1 } 
        }
    ],
    counter = 0,
    bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ 
        "_id": { "$in": doc.uniqueIds },
        "difficultyrating": { "$lt": doc.maxRating }    
    }).remove();

    counter++;
    if ( counter % 500 == 0 ) {
        // Execute per 500 operations and re-init.
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.mycollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    }
});

// Catch any under or over the 500's and clean up queues
if (counter % 500 != 0)
    bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Wow, That's a lot of code. Thak you so much. That's exactly what I needed.