# pymongo: remove duplicates (map reduce?)

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I do have a Database with several collections (overall ~15mil documents) and documents look like this (simplified):

```
{'Text': 'blabla', 'ID': 101}
{'Text': 'Whuppppyyy', 'ID': 102}
{'Text': 'Abrakadabraaa', 'ID': 103}
{'Text': 'olalalaal', 'ID': 104}
{'Text': 'test1234545', 'ID': 104}
{'Text': 'whapwhapwhap', 'ID': 104}
```

They all have an unique _id field as well, but I want to delete duplicates accodring to another field (the external ID field).

First, I tried a very manual approach with lists and deleting afterwards, but the DB seems too big, takes very long and is not practical.

Second, the following does not work in current MongoDB versions anymore, even though anyone is suggesting it.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { ID: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )
```

So, now I'm trying to create a map reduce solution, but I dont really know what Im doing and especially have difficulty using another field (not the database _id) to find and delete duplicates. Here is my bad first approach (adopted from some interent source):

```
map = Code("function(){ if(this.fieldName){emit(this.fieldName,1);}}")
reduce = Code("function(key,values) {return Array.sum(values);}")
res = coll.map_reduce(map,reduce,"my_results");

response = []
for doc in res.find():
    if(doc['value'] > 1):
        count = int(doc['value']) - 1
        docs = col.find({"fieldName":doc['ID']},{'ID':1}).limit(count)
        for i in docs:
            response.append(i['ID'])

coll.remove({"ID": {"$in": response}})
```

Any help to reduce any duplicates in the external ID field (leaving one entry), would be very much apprechiated ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use the **[`aggregation framework`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** which has better performance than map-reduce. Consider the following aggregation pipeline which as the first stage of the aggregation pipeline, the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator groups documents by the `ID` field and stores in the `unique_ids` field each `_id` value of the grouped records using the **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet)** operator. The **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator adds up the values of the fields passed to it, in this case the constant 1 - thereby counting the number of grouped records into the count field. The other pipeline step **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** filters documents with a count of at least 2, i.e. duplicates.

Once you get the result from the aggregation, you iterate the cursor to remove the first `_id` in the `unique_ids` field, then push the rest into an array that will be used later to remove the duplicates (minus one entry):

```
cursor = db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        {"$group": {"_id": "$ID", "unique_ids": {"$addToSet": "$_id"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$match": {"count": { "$gte": 2 }}}
    ]
)

response = []
for doc in cursor:
    del doc["unique_ids"][0]
    for id in doc["unique_ids"]:
        response.append(id)

coll.remove({"_id": {"$in": response}})
```

Comment: Mongodb 2.6 is telling me DeprecationWarning: remove is deprecated. Use delete_one or delete_many instead.

Comment: How can I do this if I have another column with e.g. "date_uploaded" and want to make sure that I always keep the last instance?

Comment: You don't need to iterate over `doc["unique_ids"]` and append them, you can just `extend` it like `response.extend(doc["unique_ids"])`.

Answer (score 5):

> First, I tried a very manual approach with lists and deleting afterwards, but the DB seems too big, takes very long and is not practical.

The best bet is using the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline to find those documents that are duplicate. The first stage in the pipeline is the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage where you group your documents by the *duplicated key* then use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operators which respectively return an array of all `_id` for each group and the *count* of elements in the group. The next and last stage in the pipeline is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage to return only those result where there is duplicate "ID". From there you then iterate the cursor and update each document using ["bulk"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html) operations.

```
pipeline = [{'$group': {'_id': '$ID', 'count': {'$sum': 1}, 'ids': {'$push': '$_id'}}},
    {'$match': {'count': {'$gte': 2}}}]

bulk = db.collection.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
count = 0
for document in db.collection.aggregate(pipeline):
    it = iter(document['ids'])
    next(it)
    for id in it:
        bulk.find({'_id': id}).remove_one({'_id': id})
        count = count + 1
        if count % 1000 == 0:
            bulk.execute()
    if count > 0:
        bulk.execute()
```

---

MongoDB 3.2 deprecates `Bulk()` and its associated methods so you will need to use the [`bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) method to execute your request.

```
from pymongo import DeleteOne

request = []
for document in db.collection.aggregate(pipeline):
    it = iter(document['ids'])
    next(it)
    for id in it:
        requests.append(DeleteOne({'_id': id}))
db.collection.bulk_write(requests)
```

---

You can also do this in the shell as shown in the accepted answers to [remove dups from mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557053/remove-dups-from-mongodb) and [How to remove duplicates with a certain condition in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894443/how-to-remove-duplicates-with-a-certain-condition-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 5):

My solution was also using aggregate.
You pick the field which is replicated for the aggregation.
The result will be a list of collection of duplicates. Every position will hold together a group of duplicates.
You interate over the list ignoring the first element of each every group to preserve it, and delete the rest. You do it for every collection of dupliates.
See bellow:

```
replic = db.<YOUR_COLLECTION>.aggregate([            # Cursor with all duplicated documents
    {'$group': {
        '_id': {'<FIELD_DUPLICATED>': '$<FIELD_DUPLICATED>'},     # Duplicated field
        'idsUnicos': {'$addToSet': '$_id'},
        'total': {'$sum': 1}
        }
    },
    {'$match': { 
        'total': {'$gt': 1}    # Holds how many duplicates for each group, if you need it.
        }
    }
])
                          # Result is a list of lists of ObjectsIds
for i in replic:
    for idx, j in enumerate(i['idsUnicos']):             # It holds the ids of all duplicates 
        if idx != 0:                                     # Jump over first element to keep it
            <YOUR_COLLECTION>.delete_one({'_id': j})     # Remove the rest
```

You can try "delete_many" to improve performance.