# how to delete duplicates record from a mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, aggregation-framework

i have a mongoDB collection with more that 5 millions records. from that i need to delete the duplicate entries. here is the code which i tried,

```
        from pymongo import MongoClient
        conn=MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
        db=conn.test

        cursor=db.coll.aggregate(
            [
                {"$group": {"_id":{"Instrument Name":"$Instrument Name","High":"$High","Low":"$Low","V":"$V","Date":"$Date","Close":"$Close","Open":"$Open"}, "unique_ids": {"$addToSet": "$_id"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}

            ],
            {
                'allowDiskUse': 'true'
            }

        )


        response = []
        for doc in cursor:
            del doc["unique_ids"][0]
            for id in doc["unique_ids"]:
                response.append(id)

        db.coll.remove({"_id": {"$in": response}})
```

but when i try to execute this code i am getting an error like,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "delete_duplicate.py", line 12, in 
>         'allowDiskUse': 'true'
>         TypeError: aggregate() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

when i run the code in a small data set without allowDiskuse its deleting the duplicate entries successfully.But when i trying in large data set it's throwing an error like i need to use allowdiskuse if i used that too am geeting the eror which i mentioned above.I am using MongoDB 3.0 version. so ensureIndex will not work in my platform.so please anybody help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Try `{ allowDiskUse: true }`. Without the quotes

Comment: With the Python driver, all options are passed as keyword argument. Thus you need to do `allowDiskUse=True`. Also this is not the best way to remove the duplicates. You really need a different approach using bulk operation. see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34738547/3100115)

Comment: i tried these ways too but it's trowinng an error like invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cursor = [{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "Instrument Name": "$Instrument Name",
            "High": "$High",
            "Low": "$Low",
            "V": "$V",
            "Date": "$Date",
            "Close": "$Close",
            "Open": "$Open"
        },
        "unique_ids": {
            "$addToSet": "$_id"
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}]
```

Then call

```
result = coll.aggregate(cursor, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ensure_index()` for some unique column you want on your database , which  will delete all duplicate entry  for column you have mentioned from your database then you all left is distinct entries so, for any query you will do from script will not gives you duplicate records in your result.