# Pymongo Remove duplicates with condition in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Thanks for reading my question.

Please execuse any mistakes, i'm working on improving my English.

I have **> 4000** records in my **MongoDB**, this is one of my records :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5763821ffefb61074041477e"),
    "sessionId" : "5138A3B4A5966CE4B2203B8BFC90055F",
    "objects" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "334449673730",
            "point" : 0.5
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "790373008255",
            "point" : 0.5
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "790373008255",
            "point" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "572453522243",
            "point" : 0.5
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "572453522243",
            "point" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

My result, i want to delete duplicate `id` but keep the `point` : 1.0

**Result :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5763821ffefb61074041477e"),
    "sessionId" : "5138A3B4A5966CE4B2203B8BFC90055F",
    "objects" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "334449673730",
            "point" : 0.5
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "790373008255",
            "point" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "572453522243",
            "point" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I follow this post : [How to remove duplicates with a certain condition in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894443/how-to-remove-duplicates-with-a-certain-condition-in-mongodb) 
its similary with my question but i don't know why result as not as i want :

```
pipeline = ([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            #"uniqueIds": { "$addToSet": "$_id" },
            "Point": { "$max": "$point" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "count": { "$gte": 1 }
        }
    }
])

for test_item in collection_forTest.aggregate(pipeline):
    print(test_item)
```

**Result :**

> {'Point': None, 'count': 1, '_id': None}

I can use python code, load all records, check where same `id` in list, compare if `point = 1` and remove same record with `point != 1` but i think its slower than **aggregation**

Can you help me with my problem for all > 4000 records ?
Thanks very much !

Comment: @chridam , when i find duplicate `id` in record, i delete `id` with point < 1 and keep all 'id` with point = 1. You can see result i want in my question.

Comment: @chridam In my record, i only have `point : 0.5` and `point:1.0` and there are no another `point` with diference values.