# Removing all duplicates (based on a field) in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database (100 GB), there are some duplicates in there which I wish to remove. What would be an easy way to go about this ?

I am using MongoDB 3.0 and pymongo to interact with it. The collection looks like :

```
{"kmer":"AATACAATT","species":"Sachromyces",..........}
```

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557053/remove-dups-from-mongodb?